# Last grid rows are displayed on top of each other in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm adding rows to a grid in the code behind, but each time some of the rows at the end get displayed on top of each other (overlapping; as though they were in the same row). I know that the row numbers I'm setting are not the same, and that each row has a height of auto.

The grid has no fixed height but is within a tab header of fixed height. I'm using a scroll bar with the grid and that works fine (it expands when I add more items), but there are always some number of rows at the end that are overlapping. So it's not like the grid is only accepting a fixed number or is staying at a fixed length. Even if I add a few rows, and the grid only takes up half the screen, the last couple of rows will be overlapping at the end.

Nothing I try to do with the grid seems to change anything - I tried setting the height to auto, to a fixed height, it was all the same. I'm really confused as to what is going on.

Any suggestions would be extremely appreciated. I know a DataGrid might work better here but for now I need to stick with this grid.

This is my xaml code:

```
<TabControl Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="15" Height="640">
   <TabItem>
       <TabItem.Header>
           <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Height="23" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Image Source= "image.png" Margin="0,-3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="17" />
                    <TextBlock Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center">text</TextBlock>
           </StackPanel>
       </TabItem.Header>
       <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
           <Grid Name="myGrid">
              <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="350"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
              </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

              <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="5"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="20"/>
                  <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
              </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      </Grid>
     </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem/
    ...
```

And in the code behind I am adding rows (to the existing ones) in this way:

```
RowDefinition rowNew1 = new RowDefinition();
rowNew1.Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto); 
myGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowNew1);

TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
tb.Text = some_string;
myGrid.Children.Add(tb);
tb.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0);
Grid.SetRow(tb, some_number);
```

Comment: FYI, there's no such thing as "WPF C#".

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me. Make sure the row number you're setting it to is in fact the correct index:

```
Grid.SetRow(tb, myGrid.RowDefinitions.IndexOf(rowNew1));
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I have checked the row numbers and they are all correct. It's still doing the same thing though... What would cause it to do something like that? Is it a problem with the grid, or the tab header, or the rows, or where should I be looking? And thanks for the tip about wpf C# @JohnSaunders, won't happen again

Comment: Have you pasted this code in a clean project? Cause I did and it works fine. The only thing I can think of is an older version of VS maybe? I'm on 2012 express. If something in your project is doing it then something must be changing the styling.

Comment: Thanks again. Could it be because I am adding the rows in a loop? Or because of the tab? These didn't seem likely though

Comment: Doesn't seem likely to me either. If you're able to create a standalone demo of the problem and make it available for download then I'd be happy to have a look at it for you.